# MATLAB: How to store clicked coordinates using ButtonDownFcn

Tags: matlab, save, coordinates

**Goal:** To perform several clicks in one figure, containing an image displayed with imshow and save the coordinates of the "clicked" point(s), to be used in further operations.

**Notes:** I know about the functions `getpts`/`ginput` but I would like to perform this without using them. Is this possible using `ButtonDownFcn`? (see the following code)

```
function testClicks
img = ones(300); % image to display
h   = imshow(img,'Parent',gca);
set(h,'ButtonDownFcn',{@ax_bdfcn});

function ax_bdfcn(varargin)
a = get(gca,'CurrentPoint');
x = a(1,1);
y = a(1,2);
```

At this stage the variables `x` and `y` only "live" inside `ax_bdfcn`.
How can I make them available in the `testClicks` function? Is this possible using `ButtonDownFcn`? Is this a good approach?

Thanks a lot.

***EDIT1:***
Thanks for the answer Shai. But I still cannot accomplish what I intended.

```
function [xArray, yArray] = testClicks()
img = ones(300); % image to display
h   = imshow(img,'Parent',gca);
x = [];
y = [];
xArray = [];
yArray = [];
stop = 0;
while stop == 0;
    set(h,'ButtonDownFcn',{@ax_bdfcn});
    xArray = [xArray x];
    yArray = [yArray y];
        if length(xArray)>15
            stop = 1;
        end
end

    function ax_bdfcn(varargin)
        a = get(gca, 'CurrentPoint');
        assignin('caller', 'x',  a(1,1) );
        assignin('caller', 'y',  a(1,2) );
    end
end % must have end for nested functions
```

This code (buggy!) is the closest I can get to what I want (after all the clicking, having an array with the x and y coordinates of the clicked points). I am clealy not understanding the mechanics for the implementation of this task. Any help?

Comment: The problem with your code is that`testClicks` (ignoring the `while` loop) returns right after the image is created, and therefore, `xArray` and `yArray` are empty. You might need to use `assignin('base',...)` to overcome this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways

1. Using [nested functions](http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab/examples.html?file=/products/demos/shipping/matlab/nesteddemo.html)

   ```
   function testClicks
      img = ones(300); % image to display
      h   = imshow(img,'Parent',gca);
      set(h,'ButtonDownFcn',{@ax_bdfcn});
      x = []; % define "scope" of x and y 
      y = [];  

      % call back as nested function
      function ax_bdfcn(varargin)
          a = get(gca,'CurrentPoint');
          x = a(1,1); % set x and y at caller scope due to "nested"ness of function
          y = a(1,2);
      end  % close nested function
   end % must have end for nested functions
   ```
2. Using [`assignin`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/assignin.html)

   ```
   function ax_bdfcn(varargin)
        a = get(gca, 'CurrentPoint');
        assignin('caller', 'x',  a(1) );
        assignin('caller', 'y',  a(2) );
   ```
3. Using `'UserData'` property of figure handle

   ```
   function ax_bdfcn(varargin)
        a = get(gca, 'CurrentPoint');
        set( gcf, 'UserData', a(1:2) );
   ```

   `'UserData'` can be accessed (as long as the figure is alive) using `cp = get( gcf, 'UserData');`.

**EDIT:**
An example of a way to "communicate" the clicked locations to `'base'` workspace

```
function ax_bdfcn(varargin)
   a = get(gca,'CurrentPoint');
   % the hard part - assign points to base
   if evalin('base', 'exist(''xArray'',''var'')')
      xArray = evalin('base','xArray');
   else 
      xArray = [];
   end
   xArray = [xArray a(1)]; % add the point
   assignin('base','xArray',xArray); % save to base
   % do the same for yArray
```

After calling `testClicks` there are NO `xArray` or `yArray` variables in the workspace (at least there shouldn't). After the first click these two variables will "miraculously" be created. After every other click these two arrays will increase their size until you close the figure.

Comment: +1 for listing multiple methods. Personally, I'd go for a nested function/closure if possible, and `UserData` otherwise. I would avoid `assignin`, since it's harder to debug.

Comment: Thanks again @Shai. Indeed now the variables are stored in the workspace but this raises the problem of _how_ to use them inside the testClicks function since they do not seem to live inside that function...

Comment: @fnery you may use `assignin('caller',...)` and `evalin('caller',...)` instead of `'base'`...